# how can i parse and foreach json tree on objective c

Tags: objective-c, json, parsing, nsarray

2015-10-13 16:42:55.391 JsonProject[30384:1471391]

```
requestReply: (
         {
         DNumb = 512421421;
         DTempData = "";
         DUUID = 12;
         Id = 1;
     },
         {
         DTempData = "";
         Id = 2;
     },
         {
         DTempData = "";
         Id = 3;
     },
         {
         DTempData = "";
         Id = 4;
     },
         {
         DTempData = "";
         Id = 5;
     },
         {
         DTempData = "";
         Id = 6;
     },
         {
         DTempData = "";
         Id = 7;
     },
         {
         DNumb = String;
         DTempData = "";
         DUUID = String;
         Id = 8;
     },
         {
         DNumb = 1234;
         DTempData = "";
         DUUID = 4567;
         Id = 9;
     },
         {
         DTempData = "";
         Id = 10;
     },
         {
         DTempData = "";
         Id = 11;
     },
         {
         DTempData = "";
         Id = 12;
     },
         {
         DNumb = Message;
         DTempData = "";
         DUUID = isNotReal;
         Id = 13;
     } )
```

This is json data after post method,

```
NSDictionary* responseA = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];

        NSLog(@"requestReply: %@", responseA[@"GetVerifiedDevices"]);
```

how can i reach members? also check is available any number or character?

i was working on C# and i do use foreach, is there parse this data?

Thanks

Comment: Add the code you have to the question.

Comment: `responseA[@"GetVerifiedDevices"]` seems to be a NSArray where you can use a for loop. `for (NSDictionary *aDictionary in responseA[@"GetVerifiedDevices"]){}`?